# Writing a function that is sum of functions

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have the following excercise to do:

```
Code a function that will be a summation of a list of functions.
```

So I think that means that if a function get list of functions [f(x);g(x);h(x);...] it must return a function that is f(x)+g(x)+h(x)+...

I'm trying to do code that up for the general case and here's something I came up with:

```
let f_sum (h::t) = fold_left (fun a h -> (fun x -> (h x) + (a x))) h t;;
```

The problem is I'm using "+" operator and that means it works only when in list we have functions of type

```
'a -> int
```

So, can it be done more "generally", I mean  can we write a function, that is a sum of ('a -> 'b) functions, given in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can make plus function to be a parameter of your function, like

```
let f_sum plus fs = 
  let (+) = plus in
  match fs with 
  | [] -> invalid_arg "f_sum: empty list"
  | f :: fs -> fold_left ...
```

You can generalize even more, and ask a user to provide a `zero` value, so that you can return a function, returning zero if the list is empty. Also you can use records to group functions, or even first class modules (cf., `Commutative_group.S` in Core library).